# how to create a slideshow with multiple images moving left or right one at a time

Tags: slideshow

i have been trying to create a slideshow with multiple images supposing 7 side by side and ateach some time one picture moves to the right or left like in this website i could not create the javascript code and i dont know jquery right now it would be really helpful if someone help me with some demo on some website or the code itself. you can see the actual one i like to have here in this link [example]: http://www.kanald.com.tr/ "click here to see the slider"
thank all of you in advance.
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try out : http://wowslider.com/

Its a jQuery Image Slideshow Plugin, hope it helps you out.